# How to verify that $rk(L)+rk(J)=1+rk(L)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-graph-theory

I know that it has been proved on this site that $\operatorname{rank}(A + B) ≤ \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$.

What I still want now is an application of this theorem or the method of proving this theorem to show that $\operatorname{rank}(L + J) =1 + \operatorname{rank}(L)$.

L is a Laplacian matrix of a simple graph (V,E), and J is a square matrix whose entries are ones and has the same dimension of L.

I am sure this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $rk(L+J)\leq 1+rk(J)$. We want to prove the equality.
Write $$L=D-A,$$ where $A$ is the adjacency matrix and $D$ the diagonal matrix whose diagonal is given by the degrees of the vertices.

Moreover define the hyperplane

$$H=\left\{v\in \mathbb R^n|\sum v_i=0 \right\}.$$

Observe that 
$$H=\ker(J)$$
I would do it in three steps

1) $\ker(L+J)\cap H \subseteq \ker (L)$.

2) $\ker(L+J)\subseteq H$ (Hence $\ker(L+J)\subseteq \ker(L)$).

3) $\exists u\in \ker(L)\smallsetminus \ker(L+J)$.

Proof of 1:
If $v\in\ker(L+J)\cap H$, then $$0=(L+J)v=Lv.$$

Proof of 2:
If $v\in \ker(L+J)$ then $$0=v^t(L+J)v=v^tLv+\left(\sum v_i\right)^2$$
Since $L$ is symmetric positive-semidefinitive, it must be that both
$$v^tLv=\left(\sum v_i\right)=0,$$
therefore $v\in H$.

Proof of 3:
Just pick $v=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$.
We have $Lv=0$ and $(L+J)v=nv$.

CONCLUSION:
$$\dim \ker(L+J)+1\leq \dim \ker(L)$$
and so 
$$rk(L+J)\geq 1+rk(L)$$